# Building a blackberry application to be invoked by another blackberry application

Tags: blackberry

was wondering if there was a way to build an application that its screens can be called from another application and values can be passed back and forth between the two apps, taking a cull from the Invoke API

the link http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Launch-a-third-party-application-from-another-third-party/ta-p/444753

just shows how to launch one application from another, however i want to launch a specific screen in a separate application and get results from it into the calling application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IPC mechanism available in Blackberry, using Global Events. Check the following link : [How to communicate with other applications](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11938/Communicate_with_other_BlackBerry_Java_applicatis_509284_11.jsp)

In short, two applications A and B can communicate by defining an unique id (long) to identify the messages destined to each other. Once this id is defined in both the applications,

- To send a message from application A, use postGlobalEvent
- To receive messages from application B implement GlobalEventListener.

Complete example is shown [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Global-Events-and-Global-Event-Listeners/ta-p/444814)